# Deleting formula when value is null

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm hoping there is a quick way to delete formulas in cells if the result in Null.

Specifically, using IFERROR, I have set up my formulas to read "" (i.e., blank) if the result of the formula is an error. While the cells look blank, they still contain the formula; therefore, I can't run statistical analyses (using XLSTAT) on the data because they are viewed as non-numerical cells. I tried Find and Replace but that didn't work. Given the high number of columns and volume of data, filtering each row for "blanks" and deleting those cells manually would take a long time. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Guessing you don't know VBA so do a find/replace `""` to some random string then find replace said random string?

Comment: Once you have the sheet *looking* the way you want, select the whole sheet, paste special into another sheet with only values.  Then run the analysis on the second sheet.

Comment: i'd suggest remove IFERROR and bring back the errors to the cells. Select the region where u want to delete the error cells. Hit Ctrl+G. a "Go To" window will appear. Click Special. Select Formula, uncheck all but the Errors checkbox. Click Ok. Then hit the delete on your keyboard.

Comment: KS Sheon- that is the perfect fix. Thank you all! I appreciate your chiming in and offering suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this short macro:

```
Sub SheetFixer()
   Dim r As Range, rng As Range
   On Error Resume Next
   Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Error.Number = 0
      On Error GoTo 0
      MsgBox "No formulas on sheet."
      Exit Sub
   End If

   For Each r In rng
      If r.Value = "" Then r.Clear
   Next r
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Gary's Student. I am not too familiar with macros but this is good to know. I was able to use KS Sheon's fix.